# App not appear in Notification Center in Setting, only restart the phone works

Tags: ios, notifications, setting, notificationcenter

I'm troubled by this problem a long time. Please help me.
When first install my app, I register the notification by this code:

```
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
```

Then my app will appear in Notification Center in Setting.

But when I uninstall my app, then download it from the App Store, open it ,and register the notification, but it will not appear in the Notification Center in Setting, only I reboot the phone.

And I find other apps are ok. Why? What I should do?

Wait for your help. Thanks.